# Install EclipseLink in Oracle Weblogic 12c

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, eclipselink, oracle12c

Help me, please, how to install EclipseLink in Weblogic 12c correctly? I have already conducted many experiments and all without results (((

I tried on this manual: https://dzone.com/articles/updating-eclipselink-weblogic

I downloaded the `eclipselink-2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a.zip` version from the Eclipse website. I took the `Archive -> jlib / eclipselink.jar` file from the archive.

Then I made the following directory structure:

```
./
├── lib
│   └── eclipselink.jar
└── META-INF
    ├── application.xml
    ├── MANIFEST.MF
    └── weblogic-application.xml
```

Here are the contents of all files:

**META-INF/application.xml:**

```
<application>
  <display-name>eclipselink-shared-lin</display-name>
  <module>
    <java></java>
  </module>
</application>
```

**META-INF/MANIFEST.MF:**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: lib/eclipselink.jar
Extension-Name: eclipselink
Specification-Version: 2.0
Implementation-Version: 2.7.4
```

**META-INF/weblogic-application.xml:**

```
<weblogic-application>
  <prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>org.eclipse.persistence.*</package-name>
  </prefer-application-packages>
</weblogic-application>
```

After that, I used `jar` to create a package that called `eclipselink-shared-lin.ear`
I did everything according to the manual. After that, I tried to install this EAR file on Weblogic 12c.
I got this error:

[image]

In the logs, I do not see error messages, there is such a warning that some version is not indicated, but it is written that this edition of the server automatically uses the last one:

```
<Jun 17, 2019 11:11:37,327 AM UTC> <Warning> <Munger> <BEA-2156203> <A
 version attribute was not found in element "application" in the 
deployment descriptor 
/home/cuba/weblogic_12/wls12213/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/
AdminServer/tmp/.appmergegen_1560769897253_eclipselink-shared-
lin.ear/META-INF/application.xml. A version attribute is required, but 
this version of the WebLogic Server will assume that the latest version is 
used. Future versions of WebLogic Server will reject descriptors that do 
not specify the Java EE version. To eliminate this warning, add an 
appropriate "version=" to element "application" in the deployment 
descriptor.>
```

Please help me solve this problem!

Log files - https://files.haulmont.com/b5f57f32859b

**UPDATED:**
I'm tryed to install only JAR of EclipseLink< without making EAR... 
And it's done! 
It's right? How to check the correctness?
[image]
**UPDATED 2:**
This variant does not work with my applications that use EclipseLink (((

Comment: Check you have deployed your ear as a shared lib and not as an application. Review server's log files (weblogic*.log) if there is any error relative to your deployment. THis warning should not refrain from deploying your sl.

Comment: How I can do this? I'm tried as application: Deployment - > Install.....
How install shared library?

Comment: I do not get to the step where you can choose how to install the application - as an application or as a library. I load the file, click "Next" and see the error that is indicated in the question.

Comment: once you have selected your ear file the console should display a screen asking how to deploy it, as an application or a SL.

Comment: Step-by-step: Deployment - Install - Upload your files - Deployment archive - Choose - Select EAR-file from local computer - Next - Success upload - Choose EAR-file - Next - Error from my question

Comment: did you check you server log ?

Comment: I didn't find any weblogic*.log files...

Comment: under $DOMAIN_HOME/servers/<server name>/logs/<server name>*.log

Comment: In file `AdminServer.log` - nothing interesting. In file `base_domain.log` - same error:  <A version attribute was not found in element "application" in the deployment descriptor /home/cuba/weblogic_12/wls12213/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/.appmergegen_1560955698512_eclipselink-shared-lin.ear/META-INF/application.xml. A version attribute is required, but this version of the WebLogic Server will assume that the latest version is used. Future versions of WebLogic Server will reject descriptors that do not specify the Java EE version. To eliminate this warn.......

Comment: Add log-files download links to end of my question

Comment: Update my question. Add JAR-deployment